# Hide Spotify from Windows 7 Task Bar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, spotify

When Spotify is running, it shows a little icon in the activity field. On most operative systems, closing the Spotify window minimizes the player to the activity window, freeing up space in the task bar - but not in Windows 7, it seems.

I think it's a little uneccessary to have two icons in almost the same place that does almost the same thing. Is there anyway to hide a program icon from the task bar, in this case specifically Spotify?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can right click the tray icon and 'check' "Hide from Taskbar when Closed".

And then click the cross :)

I had the same problem and found the [solution](http://getsatisfaction.com/spotify/topics/spotify_doesnt_hide_when_i_close_it) on Google.

Altough it would be great if it was also on the Preferences page where I looked first.

Comment: +1 for providing the source and +100 for hinting the devs to where this should have been located

Comment: It should also be by default, with the classical notification that programs with that same desired behaviour show if you will.

Comment: Not working on Windows 8. Just doesn't show that option any more... I'm beginning to hate Spotify...